Do random uniform triangles on a unit circle satisfy $P(R > a) \text{ }+\text{ } P(R > b) \text{ }+\text{ } P(R > c) = 1 $?
Let $a \le b \le c$ be the sides of a triangle whose vertices are uniformly random on the circumference a circle of radius $R$. There is experimental evidence for the following rational geometric probabilities
$$
P(R > a) = \frac{3}{4}, \text{ } P(R > b) = \frac{1}{6}, \text{ } P(R > c) = \frac{1}{12} 
$$
Can these be proved or disproved? If true, this would imply the elegant expression
$$
P(R > a) \text{ }+\text{ } P(R > b) \text{ }+\text{ } P(R > c) = 1 
$$

Do you really mean a circle  ? Or is it a disk (circle and its interior) ?

@JeanMarie The vertices are on the circumference. I have edited post to make this clear.

Just to be clear:  despite the header, no claim is being made about "every triangle", right?   It's a probability claim about the collection of triangles with a given circumcircle.

In fact , the title makes no sense because for a concrete triangle all probabilities are either $0$ or $1$ and the experiment showed that there are triangles with $R>c$ , in which case the sum would be $3$.

As a starting point, it might be useful to note that if $A, B, C$ are uniformly chosen points on the circle centered at $O$ and labeled in the counter-clockwise order (starting from respect to a fixed reference point), then the random vector $$(\angle AOB, \angle BOC, \angle COA)$$ is uniformly distributed on the triangle with corners $(2\pi, 0, 0)$, $(0, 2\pi, 0)$, $(0, 0, 2\pi)$. Also, $$\overline{AB}=2R\sin(\tfrac{1}{2}\angle AOB)$$ and likewise for the other two sides.

WLOG, suppose the circumradius of the triangle has circumference $1$ with radius $R$. The triangle can be scaled such that its circumradius satisfies this condition. A regular hexagon can be formed which is circumscribed by this circle. The side lengths of each smaller equilateral triangle is equal to the radius. I'll describe the location of a point on the circumference with a real number, where this number indicates the distance traveled clockwise from some point along the circumference. For example, if $A=0$, $B=\frac{1}{6}$, c=$\frac{2}{6}$ etc... Since the circumference has length $1$, the probability that a point has position within a certain range $(a,b)$ is just $b-a$ (provided $b-a<1$). Note how
$$B-A=C-B=\cdots=A-F=\frac{1}{6}$$
and the side length of the hexagon is $R$. So for two points $P_1$ and $P_2$, the below construction shows the distance between $P_1$ and $P_2$ is less than $R$ iff the difference between their position is less than $\frac{1}{6}$.

Suppose the three chosen points are $P_1$, $P_2$ and $P_3$.
Finding $\mathbf{P(R>a)}$: I'll first find the probability of event $X_1$, which is the event that $P_1P_2$ is the shortest side (so $|P_1P_2|=a$) and $|P_1P_2|<R$.
Let the position of $P_1$ and $P_2$ be $0$ and $x$ respectively. Since $R>a$, it follows $0<x<\frac{1}{6}$ or $\frac{5}{6}<x<1$. These cases are symmetric about the diameter of $P_1$, so the total probability of $P(X_1)$ will just be double the probability of one case. Consider the first case where $0<x<1/6$. For $P_1P_2$ to be the shortest side, $P_3$ has to be $x$ away from $P_1$ and $P_2$, so
$$2x<P_3<1-x$$
which has a $(1-x)-2x=1-3x$ chance of occurring. Since $x$ ranges from $0$ to $1/6$, we can integrate to get
\begin{align}
P(R>|P_1P_2|) & = 2\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{6}} 1-3x \, dx \\
& = \frac{1}{4}
\end{align}
Let $X_2$ and $X_3$ be the analogous events for $P_2P_3$ and $P_3P_1$, so that
$$P(R>a)=P(X_1)+P(X_2)+P(X_3)=3P(X_1)=\frac{3}{4}$$
Finding $\mathbf{P(R>c)}$: Note that $R>c$ implies $a,b,c<R$ since $a\leq b\leq c$. Again, let $P_1$ and $P_2$ have position $0$ and $x$. Since $|P_1P_2|<R$, it follows $0<x<\frac{1}{6}$ or $\frac{5}{6}<x<1$. These cases are symmetric about the diameter through $P_1$, so consider the first case. It can be seen that $P_3$ must lie in the interval $(x-\frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{6}$) with length $\frac{2}{6}-x$. Thus
\begin{align}
P(R>c) & = 2\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{6}} \frac{2}{6}-x \, dx \\
& = \frac{1}{12}
\end{align}
I haven't made any assumptions about which side is the longest/shortest, so there is not need to multiply by some factor. I have added two poorly drawn illustrations to indicate the regions where $P_3$ could lie.

EDIT (for $P(R>b)$): Let $Y_1$ be the event that the shortest side is $P_1P_2$ and $R>b$. If $P_1=0$ and $P_2=x$, then $0<x<\frac{1}{6}$ or $\frac{5}{6}<x<1$ as usual. Looking at the first case, there are two regions $P_3$ could be in to ensure both $P(R>b)$ and $P_1P_2$ is the shortest side, as below

The total length of these regions is $2(\frac{1}{6}-x)=\frac{1}{3}-2x$. There is a factor of $2$ to account for the two cases:
\begin{align}
P(Y_1) & = 2\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{6}} \frac{1}{3}-2x \, dx \\
& = \frac{1}{18}
\end{align}
Defining $Y_2$ and $Y_3$ to be the analogous events where $P_2P_3$ and $P_3P_1$ are the shortest sides respectively,
$$P(R>b)=P(Y_1)+P(Y_2)+P(Y_3)=3P(Y_1)=\frac{1}{6}$$

The quickest way to see the elegant formula at the end is using linearity of expectation. Thinking of each probability as the expectation of an indicator, using linearity of expectation twice gives
$$\begin{aligned}
&
P(a < R) + P(b < R) + P(c < R) \\
&\mkern24mu = E(\text{number of edges with length} < R) \\
&\mkern24mu = 3 P(\text{random chord has length} < R),
\end{aligned}$$
where the chord is between two uniformly random points on the circumference. This last probability is $1/3$, because the chord has length $< R$ iff the angle between the first and second point is between $-1/6$ and $+1/6$ full rotations. So the total expectation is $3 \cdot 1/3 = 1$.
